# Goldengate extract parameter TABLE with wildcard "*" not working

Tags: oracle, oracle-golden-gate

im new to goldengate, i want to replicate the whole schema with the use of wildcard "*" but it wont work, it works only when i specify one table and i want the whole schema.

can someone help me?

ps: im using oracle database 19c and goldengate 19 using three vms one for each database and one for the goldengate, and this is my extract parameter and its report:

> ### EXTRACT ex1 LOGALLSUPCOLS FETCHOPTIONS  FETCHPKUPDATECOLS,
> USESNAPSHOT, USELATESTVERSION DBOPTIONS ALLOWUNUSEDCOLUMN DISCARDFILE
> /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/gghome_1/DISCARD/CRM_B2B1.dsc, APPEND,
> MEGABYTES 100 tranlogoptions IntegratedParams (max_sga_size 256)
> UPDATERECORDFORMAT COMPACT exttrail
> /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/gghome_1/dirdat/ex ddl include all
> GETTRUNCATES useridalias ggadmine SOURCECATALOG EAST TABLE ggadmin.*;
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> ```
>              Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle
> Version 19.1.0.0.4 OGGCORE_19.1.0.0.0_PLATFORMS_191017.1054_FBO    Linux, x64, 64bit (optimized), Oracle 19c on Oct 17 2019 21:16:58
> ```
>
> Copyright (C) 1995, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights
> reserved.
>
> ```
>                 Starting at 2022-05-25 19:58:05
> ```
>
> ---
>
> Operating System Version: Linux Version #1 SMP Tue Apr 5 16:57:59 UTC
> 2022, Release 3.10.0-1160.62.1.el7.x86_64 Node: localhost.localdomain
> Machine: x86_64
> soft limit   hard limit Address Space Size   :    unlimited    unlimited Heap Size            :    unlimited
> unlimited File Size            :    unlimited    unlimited CPU Time
> :    unlimited    unlimited
>
> Process id: 29676
>
> Description:
>
> ---
>
> **            Running with the following parameters                  **
>
> ---
>
> 2022-05-25 19:58:06  INFO    OGG-03059  Operating system character set
> identified as UTF-8.
>
> 2022-05-25 19:58:06  INFO    OGG-02695  ANSI SQL parameter syntax is
> used for parameter parsing.
>
> 2022-05-25 19:58:06  INFO    OGG-01360  EXTRACT is running in
> Integrated mode. EXTRACT ex1 LOGALLSUPCOLS
>
> 2022-05-25 19:58:07  WARNING OGG-04033   LOGALLSUPCOLS has set the
> NOCOMPRESSDELETES and GETUPDATEBEFORES parameters on. FETCHOPTIONS
> FETCHPKUPDATECOLS, USESNAPSHOT, USELATESTVERSION DBOPTIONS
> ALLOWUNUSEDCOLUMN DISCARDFILE
> /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/gghome_1/DISCARD/CRM_B2B1.dsc, APPEND,
> MEGABYTES 100 tranlogoptions IntegratedParams (max_sga_size 256)
> UPDATERECORDFORMAT COMPACT exttrail
> /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/gghome_1/dirdat/ex ddl include all
> GETTRUNCATES useridalias ggadmine
>
> 2022-05-25 19:58:08  INFO    OGG-02623  Default source catalog name
> EAST will be used for source table name ggadmin.* mapping.
>
> 2022-05-25 19:58:08  INFO    OGG-00506  Both GETTRUNCATES and DDL
> replication are enabled.
>
> 2022-05-25 19:58:08  INFO    OGG-01815  Virtual Memory Facilities for:
> BR
> anon alloc: mmap(MAP_ANON)  anon free: munmap
> file alloc: mmap(MAP_SHARED)  file free: munmap
> target directories:
> /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/gghome_1/BR/EX1.
>
> Bounded Recovery Parameter: BRINTERVAL = 4HOURS BRDIR      =
> /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/gghome_1/
>
> 2022-05-25 19:58:08  INFO    OGG-01851  filecaching started: thread
> ID: 140431606146816.
>
> 2022-05-25 19:58:08  INFO    OGG-01815  Virtual Memory Facilities for:
> COM
> anon alloc: mmap(MAP_ANON)  anon free: munmap
> file alloc: mmap(MAP_SHARED)  file free: munmap
> target directories:
> /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/gghome_1/dirtmp.
>
> 2022-05-25 19:58:08  INFO    OGG-25340   Database Version: Oracle
> Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production.
>
> 2022-05-25 19:58:08  INFO    OGG-25341   Database Language and
> Character Set: NLS_LANGUAGE     = "AMERICAN"  NLS_TERRITORY    =
> "AMERICA"  NLS_CHARACTERSET = "AL32UTF8".
>
> 2022-05-25 19:58:08  INFO    OGG-06604  Database ORCL CPU info: CPU
> Count 1, CPU Core Count 1, CPU Socket Count 1.
>
> 2022-05-25 19:58:08  INFO    OGG-06618  Database ORCL Platform: Linux
> x86 64-bit.
>
> 2022-05-25 19:58:13  INFO    OGG-02339  Integrated capture
> successfully attached to logmining server OGG$CAP_EX1 using 60 second
> streaming duration.
>
> 2022-05-25 19:58:13  INFO    OGG-02089  Source redo compatibility
> version is: 19.0.0.
>
> 2022-05-25 19:58:13  INFO    OGG-02086  Integrated Dictionary will be
> used.
>
> 2022-05-25 19:58:13  WARNING OGG-02905  Replication of OID column in
> object tables may diverge.
>
> 2022-05-25 19:58:13  INFO    OGG-02776  Native data capture is enabled
> for Oracle NUMBER data type.
>
> 2022-05-25 19:58:13  INFO    OGG-01971  The previous message, 'INFO
> OGG-02776', repeated 1 times.
>
> 2022-05-25 19:58:13  INFO    OGG-01055  Recovery initialization
> completed for target file
> /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/gghome_1/dirdat/ex000000082,  at RBA
> 1408.
>
> 2022-05-25 19:58:13  INFO    OGG-01478  Output file
> /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/gghome_1/dirdat/ex is using format
> RELEASE 19.1.
>
> 2022-05-25 19:58:13  INFO    OGG-02776  Native data capture is enabled
> for Oracle NUMBER data type.
>
> 2022-05-25 19:58:13  INFO    OGG-01026  Rolling over remote file
> /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/gghome_1/dirdat/ex000000082.
>
> 2022-05-25 19:58:13  INFO    OGG-01053  Recovery completed for target
> file /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/gghome_1/dirdat/ex000000083, at
> RBA 1408.
>
> 2022-05-25 19:58:13  INFO    OGG-01057  Recovery completed for all
> targets.
>
> ---
>
> **                     Run Time Messages                             **
>
> ---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone encounter this problem here is the solution :

https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4498939/goldengate-table-parameter-with-wildcard-not-working/p2

i was trying to replicate the goldengate schema which is not right we use it to replicate other schemas, pretty much just grant the goldengate schema the needed privileges and replicate other schemas in the extract and replicate parameters then it should work just fine.